# Logical operator && in JavaScript and it's C# equivalent

Tags: javascript, c#, null, conditional-statements

In JavaScritp operator && can be used to invoke functions like this

```
possibleNull && possibleNull.do()
```

This executes do() method of the possibleNull object only of possibleNull object is not null. This can be handled by ?. operator. However I coud not find C# alternative for

```
let foo = _fooProvider.GetFoo();
return foo && processFoo(foo);
```

In "left && right" epxression in JS, when left variable be evaluated to "true" (generaly not null -> there are more cases in JS though), right variable is returned (or executed).

I know about C# alternative for || JS operator that works almost the same (?? operator).
Is there also a counterpart for &&?

Edit: I know that && can be short-circuited when both operands are bool. However in JS you can have right side that returns something else than bool. Left side in JS is indeed automaticaly converted to bool by the interpreter, yet righ side is just evaluated and returned as such.

I'd like to achieve something like

```
public Foo Do(Foo arg)
...
var foo = _fooProvider.GetFoo();
return foo != null && Do(foo);
```

Without using if-else or ternary operator.

Comment: `&&` does the same thing, but you can't use it as a statement itself - needs to be used as part of an `if`, `while` etc.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing somethin glike `if(foo!=null) processFoo(foo);`

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ in C# `&&` only works if both sides are `bool`.  So `foo == null` would word on the left, but if `processFoo` is a `void` method then there isn't anything you can do to make a `bool` for the right.

Comment: @juharr - very true, I dropped the ball there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The && operator in C# works just like in JavaScript, but only for `bool` operands. You can have operands of any type in JavaScript.

JavaScript uses type coercion - it assigns boolean values (true/false) to non-bool variables.

```js
0               -> false
non-0 number    -> true
[]              -> false
non-empty array -> true
undefined, null -> false
{}              -> true
```

`x && y` in JS works like this: If x coerces to false, x is returned. If x coerces to true, y is returned.

C# works the same, just with bool operands only. If x is false, x (false) is returned. If x is true and y is false, y (false) is returned. If x is true and y is true, y (true) is returned.

Now this isn't really useful for writing short code like in JS. Probably the best you can do is `if (foo != null) processFoo(foo)` or ternary `foo == null ? getNewFoo() : processFoo(foo)`.

Comment: Yes I know that I was asking if there is a way how to make c# && work with different types or alternative operator that does this. JS has || that combines c#'s || (bool operators) and ?? (null operator). I was asking if C# has another operator that takes the part of JS's && operator that C#'s && operator cant do.

Comment: There is no such operator in C# that would take any object. I just thought it was interesting that they work the same, except the type constraint of C#.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking about is logical operator "short-circuiting" where if the first condition in a multiple condition test fails, the statement processing stops.

[C# works just as JavaScript does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) in this regard:

```
& Logical AND
&& Logical AND with short-circuiting
| Logical OR
|| Logical OR with short-circuiting
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking here.

Comment: The difference is that C# requires the operands to be `bool`, but javascript does not.

Comment: Does it work without bools? The headline itself says "Boolean logical operators". In javascript && operator works without bools. It can be used to general null check like insted of "if (variable != null) do(variable)" writing just "variable && do(variable)"

Comment: @LukDeathrageProchzka JavaScript does require that the the operands be something that can convert to a Boolean and that simply means "is the operand truthy?"

Comment: @juharr JavaScript never requires operands to be anything because JavaScript is a loosely typed language and C# is a strongly-typed language. JavaScript will coerce the operand into a Boolean based on whether the value is truthy or not. In that sense, JavaScript actually works just like C#.

Comment: @ScottMarcuss well yes but no. When left operand is truthy right operant is retuned (no matter if its bool or anything else). "true && 'foo'' returns 'foo'" while "null && 'foo'" returns null. It could transformed to C# like "foo != null && 5" returning 5 when foo is not null (as left side would be true). It not possible in C# as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an OO solution to your problem. Why not implement the null patterns?

I do not know if Foo has an interface in your situation or if that is reasonabily implementable.

But instead of littering your code with null checks and maybe have all that null behaviour loatering around. (like if object is null log something)

Do something like

```
public interface IFoo { void Do(); }

public class Foo : IFoo { void Do() { /* all that stuff you wanna do */ } }

public class NullFoo : IFoo { void Do { /*log that do cannot be called on nullFoo because Foo with Code X could not be found */ } }
```

Foo probably comes from a repo or factory, when you see it cannot be instantiated. Instead of having the client check for null, just return NullFoo, let it call Do which does nothing or log that it could not be found, and go on with its day :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well this is somewhat done by Nullable struct and .HasValue property. The problem can be solved by boxing all objects in Nullable struct. However I still have to do "if (foo.HasValue) do(foo)". With your proposal I have to do "if (!(foo is NullFoo)) do(foo)". In JS I can replace the if statement by && operator like "foo && do(foo)" or more explicitly like "foo != null && do(foo)"

Comment: No that is not what i was proposing. My proposal would be that you'd simply do: do(foo). If it is of type NullFoo it means it will do nothing. But if it is Foo it will actually do something. So loose the typecheck